# need to redirect to static url based off of string patter match in uri

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2, mod-proxy, regex

I have siteminder protecting an Oracle ADF java faces app.  It appears I am going to have to intercept an http reqeust for the logout link delivered by Oracle in order to kill the siteminder session.  I have narrowed it down to a parameter in the URI logout=true always being present when a user is logging out.  I would like mod_rewrite to find this string and redirect to a static logout page defined locally to the apache proxy.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)logout=true(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://yourserver/your_static_uri [R,L]
```

Comment: He's looking for a redirect, so a `[R]` may be in order.

Comment: Agreed; should I update the answer to reflect this?

Comment: Either way - I think it's a good answer as is, if he needs to tweak the behavior then he can probably figure it out from there.  But, it's your answer, do what you see fit :).

Comment: @Marco If I could rate this answer on a scale of 5 you would have max 4 -- it's definitely on right direction, but it may produce false redirects if query string will be somehow similar to a desired one. For example: `DOlogout=trueSound&kitten=yes`. I perfectly understand that such situation may never happen (but... who knows what query strings OP may use) .. therefore treat this comment as 1 more step to make the rule even better/more accurate (and we are not talking here about case sensitivity).

Comment: @LayOne: thanks for your suggestions on how to improve my answer; later I'll take a review of it and I'll try to improve it; besides, it could be optimized for sure, adding a few special cases that allow the regular expression engine to match quickly (like if the logout parameter is the last one, or the first one).

Comment: Per my question this answer is correct. I however need to use the REQUEST_URI instead since I need to make it more applicable to more than just the QUERY_STRING.  For that I will take @Bahamat's advice and read up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}=".*logout=true.*"
RewriteRule      .* /path/to/other/location
```

You should really read the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). There's a lot you can do with it.

Comment: I think this would not work: RewriteRule, IIRC, just matches on the hostname/uri part, not on the query string.

Comment: Yup, the parameters after the `?` (the "query string" in apache's docs, which is terribly unhelpful wording in the context of a web server) is excluded from the matching pattern for `RewriteRule`.  From the docs: `the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").`

Comment: thanks much folks. was not leveraging the RewriteCond I will give it a shot and update.